# Regex In PHP That Has A Static String With Variable Numbers

Tags: php, sql, regex

I can't wrap my head around regex.

Let's say I have this string:

```
SELECT mx_posts.ID FROM mx_posts  INNER JOIN mx_postmeta ON ( mx_posts.ID = mx_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND (
  ( YEAR( mx_posts.post_date ) = 2019 AND WEEK( mx_posts.post_date, 1 ) = 26 )
) AND mx_posts.post_type = 'post'
```

I am trying to see if a string contains a substring:

```
( YEAR( mx_posts.post_date ) = YYYY AND WEEK( mx_posts.post_date, 1 ) = WW )
```

Where the YYYY could be any year, and the WW could be any week number between 1-52.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of the string you need to process as at the moment it just seems to be checking a date of some sort.

Comment: Sure. One moment.

Comment: I've added further instruction. Does that make more sense?

Comment: `YYYY` could be matched by `\d{4}` which would be any 4 digit number (not a rigorous test, granted) and `WW` could be `[1-5]?[0-9]` (assuming no leading zeroes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression would capture what we desire to capture, numerical validation would be though unnecessary, we would first find our matches, then check if those numbers follow our desired ranges, if possible:

```
(\(\s*([0-9]{4})\(\s*mx_posts\.post_date\s*\)\s*=\s*[0-9]{4}\s+AND\s+WEEK\(\s*mx_posts\.post_date,\s*1\s*\)\s*=\s*([0-9]{1,2})\s*\))
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/(\(\s*([0-9]{4})\(\s*mx_posts\.post_date\s*\)\s*=\s*[0-9]{4}\s+AND\s+WEEK\(\s*mx_posts\.post_date,\s*1\s*\)\s*=\s*([0-9]{1,2})\s*\))/s';
$str = 'SELECT mx_posts.ID FROM mx_posts  INNER JOIN mx_postmeta ON ( mx_posts.ID = mx_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND (
  ( 2012( mx_posts.post_date ) = 2019 AND WEEK( mx_posts.post_date, 1 ) = 26 )
  ( 2012( mx_posts.post_date ) = 2019 AND WEEK( mx_posts.post_date, 1 ) = 0 )
  ( 2012( mx_posts.post_date ) = 2019 AND WEEK( mx_posts.post_date, 1 ) = 53 )
) AND mx_posts.post_type = \'post\'';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/epeOki/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.